# Data of Inflation and unemployment for a Panel Data

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request, paneldata

I am looking for data of Inflation and unemployment to run a Panel Data of a Philips Curve.

Can anybody help me with some website/source that I can find data like these?

In my mind I would need too many countries (60 is enough) with this information through, for example, 2010 until 2019. Is it possible to obtain these data?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unemployment rates, check the [ILO](https://ilostat.ilo.org/). For inflation rates, see the [World Bank](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/FP.CPI.TOTL.ZG?view=chart)